# Facing issuewhile uploading .jpg file in protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

```
this.uploadFile = function() {

    var path = require('path');

    var fileToUpload = 'C:\\Users\\NEXTGEN\\Downloads\\images1.jpg',

    var absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);

    element(by.css('input[type="file"]')).sendKeys(absolutePath);
    element(by.id('uploadButton')).click();
}
```

Error thrown in console:

```
var absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);
            ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token var
```

Any suggestion will be highly appreciable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `,` instead of `;` and thus its unable to recognize it as end of line :)

Its here
`var fileToUpload = 'C:\\Users\\NEXTGEN\\Downloads\\images1.jpg',`

Notice a `,` at the end. Since you posted this - one more suggestion. Since you are already providing the absolute path - you dont need this - `var absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);`

Its needed only when you provide relative path & you need to convert to absolute before passing it onto upload element.Something like this

```
var fileToUpload = 'images1.jpg',
var absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing this. One more help I need I am getting below mentioned error  Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, *[id="uploadButton"]).                                                                                               after clicking on the upload button in the web app, how we can input the absolute path in the window diolog that gets opened.

Comment: you cannot handle window dailog .. This is a standard use case in Protractor and its described in [official documentation](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.sendKeys) - You have to submit the form behind the dialog and not click the button.